# How to change slide on a bootstrap carousel using a bootstrap button with ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I am trying to change the slide on a bootstrap carousel using the ajax code below. I have my sign up form on the first slide and will have the log in form on the second. The idea is that you can 'slide' between either forms using the button group just above the carousel that has buttons for signup and login.

I can't seem to pick out why the following isn't working..

**home.html segment where I have the buttons and include the carousel**

```
<div style="background-color: #FAF6EA !important;" class=" container col-sm-4 mt-3 py-3 pl-5 pr-4">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
        <button id="signUpBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Sign Up</button>
        <button id ="logInBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Log In</button>
    </div>
    <p class="pl-3" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: larger">Sign up to gain access!</p>
    <br>
    {% include "users/_form_carousel.html" %} // this code is show below
</div>
```

**users/_form_carousel.html that contians the carousel, the form is in a file _register.html that is being included in this code but I am not showing it in this post**

```
<div id="myCarouse" class="carousel slide">
   <div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="carousel-item active">
           {% include "users/_register.html" %}
       </div>
       <div class="carousel-item">
           <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
       </div>
       <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Here are all my js scripts (I thought I would show all of them just incase there is some sort of interference happening that someone can point out to me).**

note: the first ajax script sends form data to my flask backend and should have nothing to do with the carousel.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('form').submit(function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $('form').attr('action'), // url
            data: $('form').serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function (data) {
                alert("AJAX request successfully completed");
                console.log(data)  // display the returned data in the console.
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); // block the traditional submission of the form.
    });


    // Inject our CSRF token into our AJAX request.
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ form.csrf_token._value() }}")
            }
        }
    })
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("This has been executed"); // this alert does actually show up when the page is loaded
    // Activate Carousel
    $("#myCarousel").carousel("pause");

    // Go to the second item
    $("#signUpBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myCarousel").carousel(1); 
        alert("go to second Item"); // this should show up when I click the button but it does not show up
    });

    // Go to the third item
    $("#logInBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myCarousel").carousel(2);
        alert("go to third Item"); // neither does this

    });

});
</script>
```

Thank you for taking a look at this

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem so will just leave an answer here for documentation purposes.

I removed the following script and it now works as intended:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Bootstrap already uses js and I guess this was overriding that.